# fit a skewed data set with skew normal dist using excel

Tags: statistics

I want to fit a skew normal curve to a data set in excel.  My goal is to model incomes in geographic areas in order to get the # of people < $23,000 income, using several median values and their associated population sizes.  I graphed the population frequency distributions in excel - some are normal as expected, but some appear skewed. Ive had success modelling with the cumulative normdist function in excel, as long as the data's frequency distribution was normal-looking and not skewed.

To get the skew pdf, do I have to calculate the error function, or just use the cdf of standard normal times the st norm pdf (times 2)?

Is there a way to integrate the skew normal pdf (once obtained) in excel perhaps using rectangles under the fitted curve? How to test goodness-of-fit?

Thanks for your advice.